# How to deploy software created using specific SDK C#?

Tags: c#, windows, deployment, sdk

I am starting to use and learn C# more. So I create a basic forms application. Then I installed a separate SDK, from here: https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense "Download and Install" section. I write my application using this SDK functions.

Now, I am little confused what is the minimum code I need to put into source control or provide to users so they can run the software I developed. Do they need to install the SDK too?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

.NET Framework & The SDK Dll(s) (If there is any)

```
To work with Intel RealSense from .NET you will need two libraries next to your application - realsense2.dll and Intel.RealSense.dll.
```

Comment: oh thanks! When I reference these .dlls in my project, where should they be in my project. Which folder?

Answer (score 1):

You should be building this sdk into a library (.dll) and then referencing this library in your code's project (assuming Visual studio). You shouldn't be merging this code with your code. Then you have 2 options.

1) Distribute your code and put a note in the build instructions that this third party lib is required. This defers downloading the lib to the people using your code

2) Distribute your code with a dependency directory that contains this dll and all other required dlls that your code references. You are providing compiled versions of the libraries that you make use of.

Either way, make sure that you check the license for any open source code that you make use of and follow their required distribution steps. If you have more questions on this, or have other questions, I'm here to help. You can ask here or send me questions on Twitter @NickCGamb.

Comment: Thanks. In general is it better to provide the dll in the package or better to get user to download the dll?

Comment: I think this depends on your audience. Are you releasing this to the open source community? Then just put the dependency in the build instructions and let the consumer do it. Is this for your product development team that will be worked on by many or will need to pass through QA? Consider sending the libraries. Put the dlls in any folder that you like, in VS right click on your project, click add, click reference, click browse, browse for the dlls.